# React Context - infinite useEffect loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, react-context

I am aware of the multiple similar questions regarding this type of error both on articles and on SO as well but none of them have applied or worked for me up until this point.

So, I am using the React Context API to keep track of a state shared between multiple components:

```js
// imports removed because irrelevant

interface IMarkedPlacesContext {
  markedPlaces: Place[]
  setMarkedPlaces: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Place[]>>
  markPlaces: (places : Place[]) => Promise<void>
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const MarkedPlacesContext = createContext<IMarkedPlacesContext>(
  {} as IMarkedPlacesContext
)

export function MarkedPlacesContextProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [markedPlaces, setMarkedPlaces] = useState<Place[]>([])
 
  const markPlaces = useCallback( async (places: Place[]) => {
    const placesWithRatings : Place[] = await Promise.all(places.map(async (place) => {
      const placeRating = await FirestorePlaceRatingService.getPlaceRating(place.placeId)
      if (placeRating) {
        return({
          ...place, 
          rating: placeRating.sumRating/placeRating.reviewCount,
          reviewCount: placeRating.reviewCount 
        })
      } else {
        return(place)
      }
    }))
    setMarkedPlaces(placesWithRatings)
  }, [])

  return (
    <MarkedPlacesContext.Provider
      value={{
        markedPlaces,
        setMarkedPlaces,
        markPlaces,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MarkedPlacesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useMarkedPlaces() {
  return useContext(MarkedPlacesContext)
}
```

This component sits on the root level of my app. The function to take note of here is  `markPlaces` which fetches the corresponding rating (if it exists) from my Firestore backend, otherwise, it just gives back the original `place` object with `rating` as undefined.

Now the problem occurs when I try to use `markPlaces` in a useEffect in one of my components:

```js
const PlaceListScreen = () => {
  const { markedPlaces, markPlaces, setMarkedPlaces } = useMarkedPlaces()
  const { setPlaceInfo, focusPlace } = usePlace()
  const { navigate } =
    useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<BottomSheetStackParams>>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focusPlace) navigate('PlaceReview')
  }, [focusPlace])


  // INFINITE LOOP OCCURS HERE! :(
  useEffect(() => { 
    console.log('marking..')
    markPlaces(markedPlaces)
  }, [])


  const handlePressPlace = (place: Place) => {
    setPlaceInfo(place)
    navigate('PlaceReview')
  }

  const renderRating = (placeRating: number | undefined) => (
    <Subheading style={{flex: 0.1, paddingLeft: 15}}>
      {placeRating ? placeRating.toFixed(1) : '-' }
    </Subheading>
  )

  const renderPlaceItem = (place: Place) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePressPlace(place)}>
      <List.Item
        title={place.name}
        description={place.formattedAddress}
        right={() => renderRating(place.rating)}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

  return (
    <BottomSheetFlatList
      data={markedPlaces}
      keyExtractor={(place) => place.placeId}
      renderItem={(place) => renderPlaceItem(place.item)}
    />
  )
}

export default PlaceListScreen
```

I do not understand why calling `markPlaces` in this manner causes an infinite loop. Is it something to do with the way I pass in `markedPlaces` as a param? Or is it something to do with the way I have structured my context?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

I have a hacky work-around of the issue, what I did was to make a local state called `places` held on the component `PlaceListScreen` which essentially acts as a reflection of the main value store in the `MarkedRestaurants` Context. Instead of changing the state held within the context, I change the local state. However, this is an extremely ugly solution which I could see definitely causing problems in the future.

I've been mulling over why having the value stored in context is the cause of the infinite re-renders, but I'm still failing to see why. If someone could help me figure out why this is happening and a more appropriate solution for it that would be awesome.

Comment: Just to test comment out `setMarkedPlaces(placesWithRatings)` in `useCallback` hook in your context and see if that state change is causing the issue

Comment: Yes it seems that state change is the culprit. Any ideas on why this could be the case though? (btw the useCallback is a result of me trying some other solutions online)

Comment: This is strange because `useCallback` dependency array is empty. See if the issue still persists if you remove the `useCallback` hook, declare `markPlaces` as a normal arrow function and uncomment the `setMarkedPlaces(placesWithRatings)`.

Comment: Yes that's the original setup I had which caused the problem in the first place.